# cordova app crashes when selecting photos bigger than 3mb

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, camera, crash

I'm developing an app using Cordova and the camera plugin by cordova.
I'm having an issue where, when using the photo library as an image source, if i select an image over about 3mb, the app crashes.
I have found no consistency other than file size to my crashes.
I have added a few other fields and conditions to both the config.xml and android manifest as per other suggestions online to no avail.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem and could point me in the right direction. Testing on a nexus 5.

Comment: what is the error your getting ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hey try using "NATIVE_URI" instead of "FILE_URI" for 'destinationType' in camera options.